# Can you help me find this specific part (looks like a mudguard) anywhere?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I have 2 of these pieces and don’t know where they came from (already did some searches), but it looks similar to some mudguard pieces. I think the numbers on one piece say  0704 and 0401 and the other 0704/0402 but it doesn’t lead anywhere. Any ideas?![image][image][image]

Comment: If you don't see "LEGO" imprinted anywhere in the plastic, it's probably not Lego.

Comment: @qwr The third picture explicitly proves that. See the studs and Pubby's answer.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It’s a perfectly fine question, properly formulated and with pictures. No reason to downvote just because this is not official LEGO.

Comment: It is worth noting that LEGO has a slew of [mudguards](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=mudguard#T=A), one of which might be a suitable substitute.  If there is one that is close enough bricklink will make it easy to get it.

Answer (score 8):

Looks to be a KRE-O part (clone brand), perhaps from one of their GI-Joe sets. Dunno which set, but this should point you in the right direction.

[image]